# Changing bro logging Defaults

Tags: hostname, mac-address, bro

I want to enable logging of MAC adresses as well as hostnames using Bro. I have been using `Bro` for a while, but I am still a bit new to it.

Version: `Bro 2.5.1`

From researching this a bit, I found that I can log this by enabling  `policy/protocols/dhcp/known-devices-and-hostnames.bro` but for this, I also need to enable `policy/misc/known-devices.log`.

This will then log to a `devices.log`.

Now the problem I am experiencing is that from those files, is that this will only be logged once a day (by default).

I need this to be logged more frequently (as soon as there is the specific connection, I want that connections mac address and hostname to be logged. Is this possible?
If possible, do I need to change the defaults and where?
Or did I possibly miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a `redef` of `Log::default_rotation_interval` ([docs here](https://www.bro.org/sphinx/scripts/base/frameworks/logging/main.bro.html#id-Log::default_rotation_interval)) to something that suits your need. If you're running a cluster, consider the `LogRotationInterval` in [BroControl](https://www.bro.org/sphinx/components/broctl/README.html#log-rotation-and-archival).